# fatal error: sys/statvfs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc

I was trying to compile a program which reuires sys/statvfs.h file. I am compiling using x86_64-w64-mingw32 compiler (windows-7).

Can you guys point to a proper download or any other method to get rid of this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. `sys/statvfs.h` is part of UNIX and UNIX-like systems conforming to POSIX. It just isen't there in Windows. You could try Cygwin, but from it's use I doubt it will be there either. UNIX programs are usually pretty compatible between UNIXes, but almost never to Windows if they use the POSIX API. Try compiling it on Linux, Mac, Solaris, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes as you said it is working fine in linux.But I want to compile it in windows. Does MinGW support this file or what?

Comment: MinGW does actually port some POSIX headers to windows (check the `include` folder in your mingw installation). But this one isn't one of them, it seems.

Comment: @user1512319: No, it won't. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) might though. System programs and drivers that are written deeper into the POSIX API probably won't work well on Windows. More work is put into porting Windows programs verbatim to Linux, as most people assume that anyone using a Linux program like that has no reason to be using Windows anyway.

Comment: You would be better off using Windows API equivalent for the method that requires that header file - if you are looking for file information, try FindNextFile.